# Save and retrieve image in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I am really confused of all the different possibilities Swift has to save data and retrieve data. Save and retrieve data through userDefaults is easy, but for storing a lot of images this is not the best way to do it. Then there is Core Data, which is I think to complicated to use for such a simple task. I continued to read about DocumentDirectory, I think this is a good way to save and retrieve data. However, all the tutorials are mostly from swift 2.0 and below, and I can not read that very well. Is the document directory the best way to store and retrieve images? I am making an online application which contains downloading images from users. However, the images are all the same from the same user, so I want to store the images offline to save some bandwidth.

I want to store and retrieve images with a path I can specify in a String. Every user has a unique identifier which I want to use as a path. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Saving in your file system is definitely the best approach to use in this scenario.

Have a look to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896556/5109911

```
if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
    try? data.write(to: filename)
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

where `image` is your `UIImage`

Answer (score -1):

```
To Store Image in User default you can just simply create an extension of UI image view like  below Code Click the link to show code
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEhcr.png

How to Use::-  yourimageviewName.saveImage(),OtherImageViewName.loadImage()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcrNX.png

Comment: Please consider that your Answer is what OP is asking. It's better practice to submit code instead of screenshot.